# How can I get the default index from the pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My dataframe looks like this

[image: dataframe]

I want to access the index 135445, 135446 so that I can use them as key to retrieve data from another dataframe.
How can I access it?

Comment: Use `test.index[0]`, `test.index[1]`

Comment: @jezrael Thanks that helps. However the indices are not continuous. How can I retrieve all of them?

Comment: Do you think `test.index` ? Or you want all possible index values between first and last value like `135445,135446, 135447, 135448, 135449...` also if not exist? Not sure if understand

Comment: @jezrael I want to retrieve the indices that are in test dataframe. These indices are not continuous. For example there is no index 135448 here. I want only the indices that are here in test dataframe

Comment: OK, so `test.index` is what need.